# Looking for standard alternative to ugly multithreading

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

I have been experimenting with different ways to process data asynchronously. I have a block of code which accomplishes such a task in an image processing application, but it seems awkward to me. I am looking for suggestions attuned to current standards, or a coding convention to follow:

```
' this code is run on a background thread
Dim lockThreadCounter As New Object()
Dim runningThreadCounter As Integer = 0
Dim decrementCounterCallback As New AsyncCallback(
    Sub()
        SyncLock lockThreadCounter
            runningThreadCounter -= 1
        End SyncLock
    End Sub)
runningThreadCounter += 1
widthsAdder.BeginInvoke(widthsSlow, decrementCounterCallback, Nothing)
runningThreadCounter += 1
widthsAdder.BeginInvoke(widthsFast, decrementCounterCallback, Nothing)
runningThreadCounter += 1
bruteForceCalculateR2.BeginInvoke(numberOfSamples, pixelsSlow, decrementCounterCallback, Nothing)
runningThreadCounter += 1
bruteForceCalculateR2.BeginInvoke(numberOfSamples, pixelsFast, decrementCounterCallback, Nothing)
' wait here for all four tasks to complete
While runningThreadCounter > 0
    Thread.Sleep(1)
End While
' resume with the rest of the code once all four tasks have completed
```

I thought about `Parallel.Foreach` but couldn't come up with a solution using it since the tasks have different delegate footprints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class to initiate your work, and [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) to wait for them to complete.

This eliminates the need to have a "running thread counter", as each task can just be stored and waited upon as a group.

This would look something like (once you remove your callbacks):

```
Dim widths1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() widthsSlow())
Dim widths2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() widthsFast())
Dim bruteForce1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() numberOfSamples(pixelsSlow))
Dim bruteForce2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() numberOfSamples(pixelsFast))

' Wait for all to complete without the loop
Task.WaitAll(widths1, widths2, bruteForce1, bruteForce2)
```